# Trying to create regex pattern to not match characters, space and 200

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to **not** match characters, space and `200`.
I am able to not match characters and space using

```
/[^a-z\s]/gi
```

But I just cannot figure out how to unmatch `200` also with it.

Basically, if string has "`aBcd!@$24323 200`". Only things that are going to be matched are "`!@$24323`". How can i do it?

Comment: and what do you mean by "200" something like a 2 a 0 and a 0 with nothing between, or ist i a hexcode of a character or ... Please explain.

Comment: I have tried [^a-z\s200], [^a-z\s]|(\b200\b), [^a-z\s]|200(?!=def), ^([a-z\s]|200) and anything i can think of.. no luck.

Comment: just digit 200 for matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in JavaScript's regex flavor since lookbehinds are not supported.

If its a matter of removing the said text:

```
'aBcd!@$24323 200'.replace(/[a-z ]|200/gi, ''); // "!@$24323"
```

If you want to remove the other part it's not possible, here is a PCRE regex that will work however:

```
/[^a-z ](?!(?<=2)00|(?<=20)0|(?<=200))/gi
```

[Try it online](https://www.regex101.com/r/pB0cC5/3)

Comment: actually matched text needs to be removed from string. string will be dynamic

Comment: It's not possible with JavaScript regex since lookbehinds are not supported.

Comment: I really like that pattern. I wonder if that is the solution client wants. i hope. for backend anyway I learned a lot today about regex more.